# Python loop indexing on time stamped data

Tags: python, loops, timestamp, time-series

I'm new to Python and have a question.  I am working with time stamped data from yahoo finance.  Any variable that I create without performing a loop, such as `% chg.`, returns a result with the original time stamp still intact:

```
close_return = close_price.pct_change()
output:
2014-12-18 -0.028116
...
Name: close, Length: 2199
```

But once I put this result through a for loop, the time stamp index is replaced with the default index (0,1,2,n,...).

```
my_lambda=.94
weight=0
lambda_calc=[]
    for i in log_sq_series[::-1]:
        if i == log_sq_series[-1]:
            weight=1-my_lambda
            lambda_calc.append(weight)
        else:
            weight=weight*my_lambda
            lambda_calc.append(weight)
mylambda=pd.Series(lambda_calc, name='lambda')
mylambda
output:
0     0.060000
1     0.056400
etc...
Name: lambda, Length: 2199, dtype: float64
```

This becomes an issue for me when I perform arithmetic on two variables with two different indices.  See below:

```
somevariable=mylambda*close_return
somevariable
output:
2006-04-10   NaN
2006-04-11   NaN
...
2184   NaN
2185   NaN
Length: 4398, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, the `#` of rows double (`2199` for timestamped, `2199` for default index) because Python is working on two different indexes (I think?).  Does anyone have a solution?  Again, I'm new to Python so layman's terms would be super helpful ;)

Comment: I recommend an http://sscce.org/

Comment: The question should be very obvious through the example.  But if it is not, I'm trying to understand how I can leverage timestamps in a loop so that the loop does not default to the 0 through x index.  Or, is there a way that I can modify the output of a loop to change the index to the timestamp?  Can I create a list of timestamps and use that list over the default index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your close_return is a numpy array, you can try something like this:

```
mylambda=pd.Series(lambda_calc, name='lambda', index = close_return[:,[1]])
```

This should create series with a custom index (corresponding to first column of your `close_return`.